# I currently live in an apartment with decent free WiFi but

Tags: internet, internet-connection

I’m currently in college and I’m looking to get a gaming PC pretty soon. As of now, I use a console and the WiFI has a higher than average download speed but lags here and there when playing video games. I’m looking to see if there is a way for me to decrease connectivity issues and lag issues. Do I buy a personal router exclusively for my PC? Or is there some other way that I’m ignorant of as I tried researching it to the best of my abilities but I’m too much of a PC noob to even know where to look.

Comment: If you've a slow connection that won't be faster whatever device you connect between your pc and the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the freedom to arrange your own broadband Internet connection?  This is going to be the most effective answer.  Your current connection has two serious issues right now, potentially:

1. You are sharing it with several other users.  This makes latency and bandwidth sensitive to how much they are using the connection.
2. You are on WiFi.  WiFi is shared, single-duplex bandwidth that is affected by the number of client devices that are using it (yours, and those of others), as well as other devices and nearby WiFi networks that are on the same or similar frequencies.  (The 2.4 GHz band, in particular, is used by many, many devices.)

Getting a wired connection to your existing network may help, if WiFi is the issue, but it will not, if overall network capacity is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Its impossible to give you a 100% certain answer because these issues could be coming in to play at different places in the network.

That said -

If you ditch WIFI for an ethernet cable, you will eliminate the most likely source of problems - WIFI interference from other devices.   You will also (marginally) decrease your latencies.

A router may or may not help, depending on how you intend to connect - if you are configuring the router as an AP client, and then plug in to it via ethernet - on the assumption that ethernet is not available - this may help somewhat - IF the router has better aerials and more sensitive noise handling circuitry.

The correct way to address the problem: 
If you can plug in a computer (or do it from your console), run an MTR to to your gaming server (ie software which does a combination of ping and traceroute) and this will show you where the lag/packet loss is coming in.   You then need to tackle this issue - if the issue is in the first hop, you can probably change the way you connect (use ethernet, better WIFI, different location etc).  If the problem is outside that you will need to contact whoever is in charge of the network or get an alternative connection through another provider.

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted ?